# Keras: multiclass classification with Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning

Dataset: Labelled epidemic data consisting of number of infectious individuals per unit time.

Challenge: Use supervised classification via a recurrent neural network to classify each epidemic as belonging to one of eight classes.

My problem: I have working code, but I have a feeling it's not the best way to approach the problem. In particular, I have assumed that hyperparameters like number of units per layer, learning rate, batch size, etc. come from a discrete set, and I run a different neural network for each setting. There must be a standard (better) way of doing this?

Relevant section of working code: (Disclaimer: huge debt of gratitude to http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Dense, SimpleRNN
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.utils import np_utils
import itertools, argparse


def network_simple_rnn(data_in, out_dim, optim_type, b_size, save_file, num_classes, epochs, default_val):
        X_train = data_in[0]
        dummy_y = data_in[1]
        X_test = data_in[2]
        dummy_y_test = data_in[3]

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(SimpleRNN(out_dim, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences = False))
        model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

        optim_type = ["rmsprop", "adam", "sgd"]
        s_in = save_file
        for optim_val in optim_type:
                if optim_val == "sgd" and default_val == False:
                        lr_ = [0.001, 0.01, 0.05]
                        momentum_in = [0., 0.8, 0.9, 0.99]
                        decay_in = [0., 0.01, 0.1, 0.5]
                        nest_in = [True, False]
                        paras_in = itertools.product(lr_, momentum_in, decay_in, nest_in)
                        for l_in, m_in, d_in, n_in in paras_in:
                                save_file = s_in
                                optim_use = keras.optimizers.sgd(lr = l_in, momentum = m_in, decay = d_in, nesterov = n_in)
                                model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optim_use, metrics = ['accuracy'])
                                hist = model.fit(X_train, dummy_y, validation_data=(X_test, dummy_y_test), nb_epoch = epochs, batch_size = b_size)
                                scores = model.evaluate(X_train, dummy_y)
                                print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
                                h1 = hist.history
                                acc_ = np.asarray(h1['acc']) #ndarray
                                loss_ = np.asarray(h1['loss']) #ndarray
                                val_loss_ = np.asarray(h1['val_loss'])
                                val_acc_ = np.asarray(h1['val_acc'])

                        acc_and_loss = np.column_stack((acc_, loss_, val_acc_, val_loss_))

                        save_file = save_file + str(l_in) + str(m_in) + str(d_in) + str(n_in) + str(epochs) + ".txt"
                        print 'saving file'
                        #Write the scores to a file
                        with open(save_file, 'w') as f:
                                np.savetxt(save_file, acc_and_loss, delimiter=" ")
                        print 'saved file', save_file

        else:
                model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optim_val, metrics = ['accuracy'])
                hist = model.fit(X_train, dummy_y, validation_data=(X_test, dummy_y_test), nb_epoch = epochs, batch_size = b_size)

                scores = model.evaluate(X_train, dummy_y)
                print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
                save_file = s_in
                h1 = hist.history
                acc_ = np.asarray(h1['acc']) #ndarray
                loss_ = np.asarray(h1['loss']) #ndarray
                val_loss_ = np.asarray(h1['val_loss'])
                val_acc_ = np.asarray(h1['val_acc'])

                acc_and_loss = np.column_stack((acc_, loss_, val_acc_, val_loss_))

                save_file = save_file + str(optim_type) + str(epochs) + ".txt"
                print 'saving file'
                with open(save_file, 'w') as f:
                        np.savetxt(save_file, acc_and_loss, delimiter=" ")
                print 'saved file', save_file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #This section reads in command line arguments from a separate file
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--train_file')
    parser.add_argument('--test_file')
    parser.add_argument('--out_dim')
    parser.add_argument('--optim_type')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size') 
    parser.add_argument('--save_file') 
    parser.add_argument('--num_classes')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs') 
    parser.add_argument('--default_val') 

    args = parser.parse_args()

    train_file = str(args.train_file)
    test_file = str(args.test_file)
    out_dim = int(args.out_dim)
    optim_type = str(args.optim_type)
    b_size = int(args.batch_size)
    save_file = str(args.save_file)
    num_classes = int(args.num_classes)
    epochs = int(args.epochs)
    default_val = bool(args.default_val)

    data_in = read_data(train_file, test_file)
    network_simple_rnn(data_in, out_dim, optim_type, b_size, save_file, num_classes, epochs, default_val)
```

Comment: Your `read_data` function seems to be not defined currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This i going to be a style-review only, because after that the actual review becomes that much easier.

1. **Use a consistent number of spaces.** Currently you have 8 spaces in your functions, but 4 spaces per tab in your `if __name__ = "__main__":` part (which is a good thing to have). [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style-guide, recommends using 4 spaces per tab.
2. **Use tuple unpacking.**

```
X_train = data_in[0]
dummy_y = data_in[1]
X_test = data_in[2]
dummy_y_test = data_in[3]
```

Can be more succinctly written as:

```
X_train, dummy_y, X_test, dummy_y_test = data_in
```

3. **Use better names.** `dummy_y_test`, `s_in`, `optim_use` are all not very descriptive names. Try to come up with better ones.
4. **Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to build your save file name.**

```
save_file = "{save_file}{l_in}{m_in}{d_in}{n_in}{epochs}.txt".format(**locals())
```

Or, in Python 3.6+, using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
save_file = f"{save_file}{l_in}{m_in}{d_in}{n_in}{epochs}.txt"
```

This way you don't need to call `str` on all of them, because `format` does that for you. Also, whenever you do `"str1" + "str2"`, you create a new string (because strings are immutable in Python). For long chains of long strings, this becomes quite inefficient.

5. **Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) everywhere.** It is the more modern, recommended way to do string formatting.

```
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

becomes

```
print("{}: {:.2f}%".format(model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

or, again for Python 3.6+:

```
print(f"{model.metrics_names[1]}: {scores[1]*100:.2f}%")
```

6. **Be consistent with your `print`.** Right now you mix `print(X)` and `print X`. To be future-proof, use only the former, or consistently use the latter (You might want to add the [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tag, if you want only recommendations taking Python 2.7 into account).
7. **Use more tuples.** There are a lot of places, where you do something like `optim_type = ["rmsprop", "adam", "sgd"]`. Since you never add any type or modify it, and the only thing you do is iterate over it, you can save a tiny bit of space and use tuples here: `optim_type = "rmsprop", "adam", "sgd"`.
8. **Move argument parsing to its own function.** Just put all you argument parsing into a `parse_args` function, this way it does not clutter your code. Note that `argparse` is quite sophisticated and can take a type argument for each argument. The default type is `str`. Note that you can use `action='store_true'` to make an argument behave like a flag. This way `./script.py --default_val` will make `args.default_val == True` and `./script.py` will give `args.default_val == False`:

```
def parse_args():
    """Reads in command line arguments from a separate file"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--train_file')
    parser.add_argument('--test_file')
    parser.add_argument('--out_dim', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--optim_type')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int) 
    parser.add_argument('--save_file') 
    parser.add_argument('--num_classes', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int) 
    parser.add_argument('--default_val', action='store_true') 

    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    data_in = read_data(args.train_file, args.test_file)
    network_simple_rnn(data_in, args.out_dim, args.optim_type, args.batch_size,
                       args.save_file, args.num_classes, args.epochs,
                       args.default_val)
```

This still looks somewhat messy, mostly due to the lot of `args.X` in there. If you renamed the variables in you `__init__` to exactly the same ones of the argument, you could do:

```
def network_simple_rnn(data_in, out_dim, optim_type, batch_size, save_file, num_classes, epochs, default_val, **kwargs):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    data_in = read_data(args.train_file, args.test_file)
    network_simple_rnn(data_in, **vars(args))
```

The `**kwargs` is needed to catch all superfluous keyword arguments.